# How to change json format using API Resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to push an item `status` into array and then return through API Resource, but API resource returning error. I am trying following script to do that

```
$Games = Game::all();
return new GameResource($Games);
```

And it is return as following

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "similique",
            "type_id": 3,
            "created_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:27",
            "updated_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:27"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying following to achieve my desire json array

```
$Games = Game::all();
$DataArray = ['status' => 'success', 'data' =>$Games ];
return new GameResource($DataArray);
```

But it is returning error

`Call to a member function toBase() on array in fil`

My desire json array is following

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "similique",
            "type_id": 3,
            "created_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:27",
            "updated_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:27"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The complete error message should say it all: You are calling a method on an array. You should post the relevant code of that section as there is no `toBase()` method here.

Comment: @jeroen so I need to make an override method?

Comment: Could you also provide the code for the GameResource class?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort trust me there is nothing except laravel created API Resource

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$games = Game::get();

return response()->json(new GameResource($games));
```

Comment: Can you just read the question properly before posting an answer. It is so weird

Answer (score 1):

In your `GameResource.php` change the `toArray()` method:

```
/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'status' => 'success', // Here goes the logic which checks for success or failure. However, this depends on what you consider as "success".
   ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually problem is I am using same `GameResource.php` for lot of API's. So I need a generic solution or is there any way to without changing anything in `GameResource.php`?

Comment: When you change it inside `GameResource.php` you will have the change on all usages of this resource. How can it be more generic?

Comment: You are absolutely right, that's why I am trying different approach as like to fix in controller or if you have any other solution then kindly guide me. I appreciate for this answer and voted up +1

Comment: I guess, I don't understand your usecase. 

If you have the case that some game resources need a `status` flag and some not, you have different resources. This means you need different Resource classes.

Answer (score 0):

data is a public property of your GameResource ? then your code should be

```
return ['status' => 'success', 'data' => (new GameResource($Games))->data ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I am using this way.

Step 1: I create a generalOutput Resource.php and modify like below.

```
class GeneralOutputResource extends JsonResource
{
    private $status;
    private $data;
    public function __construct($status, $data)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function toArray($request)
    {
       return ['status' => $this->status, 'data' => $this->data];
    }
}
```

Step 2: 
 Then I just call the class like this

```
 $a_user = User::find(1);
 return new GeneralOutputResource(1, $a_user);
```

- Everytime I return the response, I will call the GeneralOutputResponse.